# Displaying <a> in Text-box value

Tags: php

I am trying to display  in a textbox value but it not displaying properly.

I am fetching following code from database

```
<a href="http://www.test.com" target="_blank">Click Me</a>
```

When i am displaying value in textbox it displays like

```
<input type="text" target="_blank" www.test.com"="" http:="" value="&lt;a href=" id="action_url" name="action_url">
```

Comment: You must be using `htmlspecialchars()` or entities so just decode it

Comment: It looks like you are showing us some data from your database, and some data from your browser's DOM inspector … but not showing us the raw HTML source or the PHP you use to generate it.

Comment: @Mr.Alien — I suspect the problem is exactly the opposite of that.

Comment: @Quentin I think so because the other are not getting converted, just the specific `<`

Comment: no am not using htmlspecialchars() data is posted correctly to db & fetched as well but when i displaying data in textbox value i get above output...

Comment: Do you mean that you need the link inside the <a> tag be set as a value of the text input tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some characters in HTML have special meaning, at least in some context. `"` for example means "start an attribute value" or "end an attribute value".

You have `"` in your data, so it will end the `value` attribute's value when encountered.

If you want to have `"` meaning "A quote mark as data" instead of "End of an attribute value" then you need to express it with the character reference `&quot;`.

The PHP function `htmlspecialchars($string)` will convert most characters with special meaning in HTML to their equivalent character references. (The second argument to that function will modify which characters are converted, so you can specify that all characters with special meaning will be changed).

Any time you have some text that you are inserting into an HTML document, you must run `htmlspecialchars` over it first.

Comment: i am newer with this so can u please explain me how to apply htmlspecialchars..

Comment: `$string_of_html = htmlspecialchars($string_of_text);`

Comment: while adding to db or fetching from db.. ?

Comment: When inserting into an HTML document (which will be shortly after fetching from the database)

Comment: +1 for Quentin... your answer is works for me.. thanks so much..